# Creation of basic lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list in Python from a text file. I would like to open the file, read the lines, use the `split` method, append them to a list. This is what I have so far. All it does is print the text file:

```
lines = []
folder = open("test.txt")
word = folder.readlines()
for line in word:
    var = ()
    for line in word:
        lines.append(line.strip().split(","))
        print (word)
```

My file  looks like this: `fat cat hat mat sat bat lap`

I want this to come out: `['fat', 'cat', 'hat', 'mat', 'sat', 'bat', 'lap']`

Comment: Do you think your ```for line in word``` within (loop-wise) ```for line in word``` is a good construct in *any programming language*?`:-)

Comment: Why do you expect `.split(',')` to split it up when there are no commas?

Comment: Definitely consider what @sascha said. Also, consider the statement "for line in word". Might want to flip the names so you don't get confused.

Comment: I should add that when you're ever in need of help with something simple like this, first consult the doc ;-): https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 3):

As other commentors have observed, variable naming should provide the **context** of what your variable is *assigned* to. Even though you can name a variable a multitude of names, they *should* be relevant!

You can use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) statement to open and close a file within the same scope, ensuring that the file object is **closed** (*generally good practice*). From then on, you can print the `lines` returned from the `readlines()` function as a `list` that is `split()` based on a `' '` delimiter.

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line.split(' ')
```

**Sample output:**

File: `fat cat hat mat sat bat lap`

```
>>> ['fat', 'cat', 'hat', 'mat', 'sat', 'bat', 'lap']
```

Comment: if there is only one line in the file I'm not sure traversing it is really necessary.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I chose to keep it in to be more robust, this way more lines can be added or removed from the text file.

Comment: Even if more lines are added to the file, then `for line in file:` would still work

Answer (score 1):

If your file only consists of one line then you don't need to do nearly as much work as you seem to think.

`str.split` returns a list, so there is no need to `append` the individual elements.  When you call `.split()` without any arguments it will split by any whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc) so to do what you want to do would literally just be:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    mywords = f.read().split()

print(mywords)
```

open the file, read the contents, split it up by whitespace, store the resulting list in a variable called `mywords`. (or whatever you want to call it)

Note that spliting by any whitespace means it will treat new lines the same as spaces, just another separation of words.

Comment: Since much has been said in this thread about variable naming, shouldn't your `mylines` be `mywords` instead? ;-)

Comment: Yes I realized that as I was going to bed. :)

Comment: Ha ha ha. I don't much appreciate poor posts like this. I think that's why there a [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) now on SO.